# Is there a way to detect if an image has been dragged and dropped into a div without moving image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a survival game using javascript, and right now I'm setting up all the functions. I have made an inventory system where you can go onto the next and previous items, and it shows the description, number, image and name of the item. Right now I have two buttons that allow you to get and drop the item, but I would like to be able to drag the image of the item from the description onto the main game screen and drop it, without actually moving the image.

I have tried detecting the position of the image when it is being dragged, and check if it's in the game screen div, but what ends up happening is that the function that is called when the image is in the right place happens even if the image is not dropped.

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
      var div = document.getElementById('div');
      var divLocation = div.getBoundingClientRect();
      var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
      var time = 0;

      img.addEventListener('drag', function() {

        p[0].innerHTML = event.clientX;
        p[1].innerHTML = event.clientY;
        p[2].innerHTML = divLocation.left;
        p[3].innerHTML = divLocation.top;

        if (event.clientX - divLocation.left >= 0 && event.clientX - divLocation.left <= 200) {
          if (event.clientY - divLocation.top >= 0 && event.clientY - divLocation.top <= 200) {

            if (time == 1) {
              alert("test");
              time = 0;
              setTimeout(1000);
            }

          }
        }

      });

      setInterval(function() {
        time++;
        if (time > 1) {
          time = 0;
        }
      }, 1000);
```

```html
<img src="download.jpg" id="img">

    <div id="div"></div>
```

I want the variable for the number of item to decrease by 1, when you drop the image into the game screen div, without moving the image, but right now when the image hovered on the div the function happens.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) - and implement `dragOver`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, but complete, drag-and-drop implementation.

Note the image is dragged, dropped, collected, *but not moved*.

You will want to click the "Full page" link in the preview. Drag the image to the dashed-bordered dropzone.

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart_handler);
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('dragend', dragend_handler);
document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('drop', drop_handler);
document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('dragover', dragover_handler);
document.getElementById('dropzone').addEventListener('dragleave', dragleave_handler);

const collectedItems = [];

function dragstart_handler(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = "dashed";
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.dataset.item);
  ev.effectAllowed = "none";
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragleave_handler(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  collectedItems.push(ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
  console.log(collectedItems);
  document.getElementById('items').textContent = `Number of items collected: ${collectedItems.length}`;
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragend_handler(ev) {
  ev.target.style.border = "solid black";
  ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
```

```css
#dropzone {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<body>
  <img data-item="mace" draggable src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <p id="items"></p>
  <div id="dropzone"></div>
</body>

</html>
```